# Working with barcode scanner in windows application C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, barcode-scanner

I develop a application for a Garments Shop to print invoices in that application I want to use the bar code scanner to automatically collect information from Item Tag that contains bar code and automatically fill all information in my form and after that I print the invoice.
Please give some suggestions how to work this problem.
I also use Microsoft.PointOfService library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, barcode scanner just sends all recognized symbols as a standard keyboard input. So, when user sets focus on a text field in your application and scans the barcode, it's the same as if user just entered the barcode symbols manually and hit "Enter" (or any other key, depending on the scanner settings).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a textbox in a form, when the barcode scans, it types the barcode characters in the textbox. Usually, some scanners can be configured to add another character at the end of the scan most commonly the new line character. With this, you can listen to the KeyPress event of the textbox, and handle the New Line character. When that gets triggered, then you can retrieve the other details in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class in my personal library to detect scanner works:

```
 public sealed class ScanReader
{
    #region Delegates

    public delegate void _DataLoaded(string ScannedData);

    #endregion

    private readonly double MyMaxMillisecondsBetweenPress;
    private readonly List<Regex> MyRegex;
    private readonly Timer TimeToNextKeyPress = new Timer();
    private string CardBuff = string.Empty;
    private bool FirstKeyPress = true;
    private DateTime Stamp;

    /// <summary>
    /// ScanReader constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Press"> Form where KeyPreview = true </param>
    /// <param name="Regs"> Regular expressions for filtering scanned data</param>
    /// <param name="MaxMillisecondsBetweenPress"> The maximum time between pressing the keys in milliseconds, default = 60 </param>
    public ScanReader(Form form, List<Regex> Regs = null, double MaxMillisecondsBetweenPress = 0)
    {
        MyRegex = Regs ?? null;
        MyMaxMillisecondsBetweenPress = MaxMillisecondsBetweenPress == 0 ? 60 : MaxMillisecondsBetweenPress;
        form.KeyPress += KeyPressed;
        TimeToNextKeyPress.Interval =
            Convert.ToInt32(MyMaxMillisecondsBetweenPress + MyMaxMillisecondsBetweenPress*0.2);
        TimeToNextKeyPress.Tick += TimeToNextKeyPress_Tick;
    }

    public event _DataLoaded OnDataLoaded;

    private void TimeToNextKeyPress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeToNextKeyPress.Stop();
        if (MyRegex.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Regex reg in MyRegex)
            {
                if (reg.IsMatch(CardBuff))
                {
                    OnDataLoaded(CardBuff);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            OnDataLoaded(CardBuff);
    }

    private void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FirstKeyPress)
        {
            Stamp = DateTime.Now;
            FirstKeyPress = false;
            CardBuff = e.KeyChar.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - Stamp).TotalMilliseconds < MyMaxMillisecondsBetweenPress)
            {
                Stamp = DateTime.Now;
                CardBuff += e.KeyChar;
            }
            else
            {
                Stamp = DateTime.Now;
                CardBuff = e.KeyChar.ToString();
            }
        }
        TimeToNextKeyPress.Stop();
        TimeToNextKeyPress.Start();
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
var myReader = new ScanReader(this, new List<Regex>
                                                {
                                                    new Regex(@"296\d{13,13}"),
                                                    new Regex(@"K%.{5,34}"),
                                                    new Regex(@"C%.{5,34}"),
                                                    new Regex(@"E%.{5,34}"),
                                                });
        myReader.OnDataLoaded += FillControls;
```